# String case conversion javascript

Tags: javascript, string, case, uppercase, lowercase

So I really need help with something thats been bugging me for some time now. I have a function which looks like this:

```
var convertString = function (str){

// Place for additional code here.

return str;};
```

And what I need this function to do is to convert the string that comes with str.

Example: I need the scentence "I really LOVE JavaScript" to be converted to "i RE#LLY love j#V#sCRIPT"

I have no idea whatsoever how to accomplish this, please help!

Comment: So you want to invert the case and change `A` into `#`? One word: ***why***?

Comment: @lonesomeday Precisely. It's a small part of an assignment I'm working on.

Comment: @lonesomeday: a typo, maybe

Comment: @BendErR Well, I'm really new to JavaScript so I don't know much about it. I've tried to make an array of the string with a for-loop, so that I can check each character, but I have no idea how to write the code for the check and conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var convertString = function (str){
    var s = '';
    for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++) {
        var n = str.charAt(i);
        s +=  (n.toLowerCase()=='a' ? '#' : n == n.toUpperCase() ? n.toLowerCase() : n.toUpperCase());
    }
    return s;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5f8Uv/)

Comment: This actually works splendid, although I do need to convert all "A"s into "#" aswell, and it seems to skip that part.

Comment: @Lemonmuncher - wasn't sure about that one, but I've edited the answer to convert both cases to #

Comment: I fixed it by adding ||n == 'A' after n=='a'. Now it works properly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using split and map

```
var convertString = function (str) {
    return str.split("").map(function(x){
        return x!='a' ? 
            x == x.toUpperCase() ? x.toLowerCase() : x.toUpperCase() 
            : "#"
    }).join("");
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I follow 'a', but I love the logic.  super simple

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:-

```
function my()
{

x= "I really LOVE JavaScript";
str="";
for (i=0; i<x.length; i++) 
{
 currStr=x.charAt(i)
 mystr=(currStr=='a' ? '#' : currStr==currStr.toUpperCase())?currStr.toLowerCase():currStr.toUpperCase();
 str=str+""+mystr 
 }
alert("final=="+str)
 }
```

And if thats a typo that you dont want to convert 'a' to '#' rather 'A' then just remove `currStr=='a' ? '#' :` part from above code.